# The service "sonata.user.serializer.handler.user" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.user.manager.user"

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I want to install SonataUserBundle with MongoDb database , 
this is my configuration files :

My config.yml

```
fos_user:
 db_driver:      mongodb 
 firewall_name:  main
 user_class:     Sonata\UserBundle\Document\BaseUser

group:
   group_class:   Sonata\UserBundle\Document\BaseGroup
   group_manager: sonata.user.mongodb.user_manager 

service:
   user_manager: sonata.user.mongodb.group_manager

sonata_user:
   security_acl: true
   manager_type: mongodb # can be orm or mongodb

sonata_admin:
  title:      Admin
  #title_logo: bundles/acmedemo/img/fancy_acme_logo.png
```

My AppKernel.php

```
        //knp
        new Knp\Bundle\MarkdownBundle\KnpMarkdownBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),

        //fos
        new FOS\ElasticaBundle\FOSElasticaBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),

        //mongo
        new Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle(),

        //sonata
        new Sonata\FormatterBundle\SonataFormatterBundle(),
        new   Sonata\DoctrineMongoDBAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineMongoDBAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle(),
        new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
```

My composer.json

```
"sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle": "2.3.0",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
"doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.2.0@dev",
"sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
"sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
"sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "~2.3",
"friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "~3.0",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.4.*@dev"
```

My Security.yml

```
security:
    acl:
        connection: default

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        SONATA:
            - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        # Disabling the security for the web debug toolbar, the profiler and Assetic.
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
        admin:
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
            anonymous:          true

        # -> end custom configuration

        # default login area for standard users

        # This firewall is used to handle the public login area
        # This part is handled by the FOS User Bundle
        main:
            pattern:             .*
            context:             user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:             true
            anonymous:          true
```

I have always this exception

> The service "sonata.user.serializer.handler.user" has a dependency on
>   a non-existent service "sonata.user.manager.user".

Help Please.

Comment: You should also post the relevant part of your security.yml

Comment: @TomToms  Done , you can see my security.yml